# How could I LINQ's GroupBy() with a boundary?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

Let's say I have a collection of elements which have a `float` property.

I was grouping by it but I found I was getting undesired groupings.

For example (with a `double` to take profit of `Random`'s `NextDouble()`):

```
void Main()
{
    var examples = new List<Example>();
    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var newPosition = rnd.NextDouble();
        examples.Add(new Example { Position = newPosition });
    }
    
    examples.GroupBy(x => x.Position).Dump();
}

class Example
{
    public double Position { get; set; }
}
```

This would lead into something like this:

> Grouping  0,00075609376689237252
>
> Grouping  0,0010980092925475954
>
> Grouping  0,0020200186418462629
>
> Grouping  0,0062832017458431429
>
> ...

Question is (worthy or not): how could I group them by allowing to have a "boundary" like... +- 0.05?

Comment: Round your double to the desired approximation in the groupby ? lik ehttps://dotnetfiddle.net/5s9jkR

Comment: Is rounding a good enought solution or you need the +- 0.05? in this case we will need a predefine set of 10 value with a step of 0.01 so we can understand how you group them together?

Comment: @xdtTransform Thanks for the tip! Rounding seems good enough since it does the job and yes, I guess the first group (0.00~0.05) would do the 10 set group.

Comment: The other way is possible With a group of value for each value. In my exemple range the result will look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlGtI.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boundary of +-0.05 is a bit unclear:

For a set like : { 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1 }
Each value is 0.01 for the next but but all are in the [+-0.05] range from 0.05.
But 0.01 and 0.06 are too far from each other.

But [rounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_) to the 2nd decimal could be enought.

```
examples.GroupBy(x => Math.Round( x.Position,2))
```

As  [bleep-bloop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9034195/bleep-bloop) commented:

> if you want to group by sets of 0,05 you could do `x => Math.Round(x.Position / 0.05)`

MCVE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var examples = new List<Example>();
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var newPosition = rnd.NextDouble();
            examples.Add(new Example { Position = newPosition });
        }

        examples.GroupBy(x => Math.Round( x.Position,2)).Dump();


        examples.GroupBy(x => x => Math.Round(x.Position / 0.05)).Dump();
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public double Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Live exemple : https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDNBgu

Comment: To add to that if you would want to group by sets of `0,05` you could do `x => Math.Round(x.Position / 0.05)`. Added to that it's also a bit more readable.

Comment: @Bleep-Bloop: Yes, add to that that what you suggest actually groups with a whole number as a key, and the OP could then cast to int to avoid comparing floats.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I don't think rounding the floats for a `GroupBy` could end up with inequality from the `Math.Round` method, while casting could overflow (although not for this particular situation).

Comment: @bleep, Added in the answer with an attribution link to your profil. You can edit anything related to that part if you want.